# Minification of Vuejs App causes browser to crash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, minify

I want to make sure that the user of this Vue application only enters correctly formatted currency values in the input boxes. To do this, I added a Regex test that makes sure the user can only type in correctly formatted values. The Regex works as expected, according to a bunch of different Regex testers I've found online for JavaScript. Everything works correctly when I'm running the app in a development environment.

However, when I use `npm run build` and use the minified version of the app, typing a non-number into the input box causes the web browser to crash. Windows Task Manager shows the CPU usage of that particular tab spike quite sharply. When using the Chrome debugger, it looks like any non-numeric character causes the app to enter an infinite loop. But, that does not happen in the non-minified version.

To recreate the problem, create a new Vue project using the Vue CLI. Edit the App.vue file to look like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Reporting/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Reporting from './components/Reporting'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Reporting
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Edit the main.js file to look like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'

import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Vue2Filters)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

You'll need to install vue2-filters, so install that using `npm install --save vue2-filters`.

Add this Reporting.vue component:

```html
<template>
    <div id="Reporting" style="min-height: inherit; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <div class="mainbody">
            <div id="content">
                <ErrorList v-if="error" :error="error"/>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">
                                State
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                Class
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                Description
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                Net Rate
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                Payroll
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                Premium Due
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="(clazz, index) in classes" :key="index">
                            <td scope="row" data-label="State">
                                {{ clazz.state }}
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Class">
                                {{ clazz.classCode }}
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Description">
                                {{ clazz.description }}
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Net Rate" class="alignright">
                                {{ clazz.netRate | currency }}
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Payroll">
                                <input type="text" v-model="clazz.payroll"/>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Premium Due" class="alignright">
                                {{ premiumDue(clazz) | currency }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr class="subtotal">
                            <td colspan="3" aria-hidden="true"></td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="alignright lighter">Premium Total:</td>
                            <td class="alignright">{{ premiumTotal() | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="subtotal last">
                            <td colspan="3" aria-hidden="true"></td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="alignright lighter">Tax Total:</td>
                            <td class="alignright">{{ taxTotal() | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="grandtotal">
                            <td colspan="3" aria-hidden="true"></td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="alignright lighter">Grand Total:</td>
                            <td class="alignright">{{ (taxTotal() + premiumTotal()) | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="formbuttons">
                            <td colspan="4" aria-hidden="true"></td>
                            <td><button class="button-sm purple" @click="onClear">Clear</button></td>
                            <td><button class="button-sm purple" @click="onSubmit">Submit</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable vue/no-unused-components */

import ErrorList from './shared/ErrorList'

export default {
    name: 'Reporting',
    components: { ErrorList },
    data() {
        return {
            error: null,
            classes: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onClear() {
            this.classes.forEach(clazz => {
                clazz.payroll = ''
            })
        },
        validate(lines) {
            for (let line of lines) {
                if (!(/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(line.quantity))) {
                    this.error = { message: 'Payroll must be in number format with no more than 2 places after decimal.' }
                    return false
                }
            }
            this.error = null
            return true
        },
        onSubmit(e) {
            let lines = []
            this.classes.forEach(clazz => {
                lines.push({
                    classCode: clazz.id,
                    quantity: clazz.payroll,
                    rate: clazz.netRate,
                    taxRate: clazz.taxRate
                })
            })
            this.validate(lines)
        },
        premiumDue(clazz){
            if (!clazz.payroll) {
                this.error = null
                return 0
            } else if (/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(clazz.payroll)) {
                this.error = null
                return (clazz.payroll / 100) * clazz.netRate
            } else {
                this.error = { message: 'Payroll must be in number format with no more than 2 places after decimal.' }
                return 0
            }
        },
        premiumTotal() {
            return this.classes.reduce((accumulator, clazz) => {
                return (clazz.payroll) ? accumulator + this.premiumDue(clazz) : accumulator + 0
            }, 0)
        },
        taxDue(clazz){
            return this.premiumDue(clazz) * clazz.taxRate
        },
        taxTotal() {
            return this.classes.reduce((accumulator, clazz) => {
                return (clazz.payroll) ? accumulator + this.taxDue(clazz) : accumulator + 0
            }, 0)
        },
        initialize() {
            this.classes.push({
                classCode: "5540",
                description: "Roofing",
                name: "CC-00002",
                netRate: 12.34,
                state: "CA",
                taxRate: 0.035
            })
            this.classes.push({
                classCode: "8810",
                description: "Clerical",
                name: "CC-00001",
                netRate: 0.68,
                state: "CA",
                taxRate: 0.035
            })
        }
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate(to) {
        this.onClear()
        this.initialize()
    },
    created() {
        this.initialize()
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Add this ErrorList.vue file (make sure to put this in a subfolder called shared under the components folder):

```html
<template>
    <section>
        <div v-if="error.message">{{ error.message }}</div>
        <div v-if="error.errors && error.errors.length > 0">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(err, index) in error.errors" :key="index"><h1>{{ err.message }}</h1></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'ErrorList',
    props: ['error']
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Now run the command `npm run build`. Then run the command `serve -s dist` to run the minified code. In the app, enter a non-numeric character into the input and it will cause the browser to crash.

Is there any reason why a minified version of this code would cause an infinite loop?

Comment: I am having a hard time reproducing the problem, because the code you shared is not really self-contained. (See [mcve]). Could you test the following: If you remove  the ` else if (/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/g.test(clazz.payroll)) {` condition, does the built version still have the error you mention? Does the error still occur if you remove the `currency` filter from what `premiumDue(clazz)` returns? It didn't catch my eye here, but maybe you are modifying `clazz` in a function that relies on it, causing an infinite update loop?

Comment: I've added some additional information that should allow you to recreate the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem starts occurring when you have a reference to `error` somewhere in your template. The Vue dev server will start warning you about 'You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.'. This is probably what is crashing your built version.

#### What does 'You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.' mean?

Vue re-renders a template with data when the data in it changes. Nothing odd going on there. If you reference a variable `numberOfUnicorns` and you add 1, because you spotted one`, you want this reflected on the screen.

An infinite update loop means that somehow during rendering a variable that is used during rendering, is changed. This is usually caused by functions that are not 'pure' <sup>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function))</sup>.

#### Why is it happening for you?

Your method `premiumDue` sets `this.error`. As I mentioned earlier, the problem starts occurring when `error` is used in the template. `this.error` is passed to `ErrorList` in your case, and then `premiumDue` is called, which sets `this.error` and marks the rendered view dirty. The view is then rerendered. Over. And over. And over.

The dev server seems to be a bit more forgiving for this kind of error and apparently stops the rerender cycle. The built version is optimised and trusts that you don't make it end up in an infinite cycle... which apparently turns into a crash when it does not turn out to be the case.

#### How do you solve it?

This is the harder part. First you need to rewrite `premiumDue` so it is pure.

```
premiumDue(clazz) {
  if (!clazz.payroll) {
    return 0;
  } else if (/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(clazz.payroll)) {
    return (clazz.payroll / 100) * clazz.netRate;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Now your validation no longer works, so lets do something about that. Your `validate` function checks if all fields are filled in, which is a bit strict for what we wanted to do. Instead we probably want to define some forgiving validate function `validatePartial`.

```
validatePartial() {
  for (let line of this.classes) {
    if (line.payroll && !/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(line.payroll)) {
      this.error = {
        message:
          "Payroll must be in number format with no more than 2 places after decimal."
      };
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.error = null;
  return true;
}
```

It is basically the same as `validate`, but instead of looping over an argument, we use `this.classes` instead. The error message is only triggered if `line.payroll` actually has something in it.

We still need to trigger it though, and I see two options for that. Before, you had it trigger on every keystroke, because every keystroke changed `this.classes`, which caused a re-render. We can emulate that by creating a watcher on `this.classes` that triggers the validate function.

```
watch: {
  classes: {
    deep: true,
    handler() {
      this.validatePartial();
    }
  }
}
```

A slightly less aggressive way of validating would be to use the `blur` event on your inputs to trigger the validation instead. You would not use the watcher. This way the error only pops up when the user is done typing.

```
<input type="text" v-model="clazz.payroll" @blur="validatePartial" />
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]